# How to Export every Action for Specific Armature as Separate FBX?

Tags: python, objects, export, select, actions

My goal is to export every action that has animation data on a specific armature into separate FBX files. This is what I have so far. But, it's not quite working right. It crashes if I do not have an armature with animation data selected when I start it. And it exports animation files for armatures that don't have the target prefix.

```
for action in bpy.data.actions:

            # Set the active action
            bpy.context.object.animation_data.action = action

            for obj in bpy.data.objects:

                if obj.type == 'ARMATURE':

                    prefix = obj.name[:9]

                    if prefix == "TRGExport" and obj.library == None:               

                        title = bpy.path.basename(bpy.context.blend_data.filepath)[:-6]

                        current_visibility = obj.visible_get()
                        obj.hide_set(False)
                        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
                        obj.select_set(True)

                        file_path = bpy.path.abspath("//")

                        obj_path = os.path.join(file_path, title + "-" + action.name + "." + "fbx")
                        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=obj_path, use_selection=True)
                        obj.hide_set(current_visibility == False)
```

Any ideas on how to adjust to make it work for my goal?